# (Regex) capture two substrings if delimiter exists, otherwise one substring and blank

Tags: regex

I want to use a regex to capture two substrings into two separate capture groups. The delimiter between Country and City is " ■" (a space followed by a black square). If the delimiter doesn't exist, then it means there is no city, in which case it should capture a blank value. Here is the text:

```
<p>USA</p>
<p>SPAIN ■Madrid</p>
<p>FRANCE</p>
```

I have the following regex, which captures everything between the `<p>` tags:

```
/<p>(.+)<\/p>/
```

How can I capture Country and City separately (or blank city if no delimiter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
/<p>(.+?)(?:\s■(.+))?<\/p>/
```

`(.+?)` is the first capture group. The `?` makes it lazy to not interfere with the whitespace.
The second group is a non-capture group due to the `?:` and it contains the second capture group `(.+)`
The `?` after the non-capture group makes the whole construct optional in case there is no city.